# Rescuing a hard drive with ddrescue

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

After following a few forums, I was able to rescue my hard drive with `ddrescue`. It took almost 24 hours, to rescue my files into a .dmg file. When it was completed I double clicked on the dmg file, and I get no mountable file system.

```
sudo ddrescue -v /dev/disk1s2 /Volumes/Backup/myvolimage.dmg rescue.log
```

Can anyone help, my first born pictures are on this hard disk, and I would truly be quite upset if I can not retrieve them.

Comment: Please add the used command(s) to rescue your hard drive! AFAIR ddrescue itself can't create a mountable dmg file.

Comment: Like I said, on one forum it stated to use this command:                               sudo ddrescue -v /dev/disk1s2 /Volumes/Backup/myvolimage.dmg rescue.log                      That's exactly what I did, however the .dmg isn't mounting.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually mount it:

- Open **Disk Utility.app**
- Click **File > Open Disk Image**
- Select the `.dmg` file.

This should allow you to mount/open the dmg file and install its contents.

Comment: I have tried this, but after selecting the disk image, nothing mounts.

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer won't help the author of the question, but just to help others who may face the same error: in my case I encountered it because I followed some online guides that advised to use **Disk Arbitrator** app before starting `ddrescue` to prevent mounting.

I was so happy when `ddrescue` finished restoring everything successfully that I tried to open .dmg file immediately after the rescue and got this error. As soon as I deactivated **Disk Arbitrator**, double-clicking on .dmg file mounted it successfully.